# Regular Expressions - Match all alphanumeric characters except individual numbers

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

I would like to create a RegEx to match only **english** alphanumeric characters but ignore (or discard) isolated numbers in Ruby (and if possible in JS too).

**Examples:**

**1)** I would like the following to be matched:

- 4chan
- 9gag
- test91323432
- asf5asdfaf35edfdfad
- afafaffe

But not:

- 92342424
- 343424
- 34432
  and so on..

The above is exactly what I would want.

Edit: I deleted the second sub-question. Just focus on the first one, thank you very much for your answers!!

Sorry, my regex skills aren't that great (hence this question!)

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us what paths you've been down, and let us build on top of your attempts. Also, you want only English letters, but you also want French letters? Accented letters aren't just French, so how do you want to define the acceptable accented ones?

Comment: Try testing your expressions with http://rubular.com/, rubular is one of the most helpful resources when crafting regexps in ruby imo.

Comment: The question's been answered. Try the different answers, if any work, problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following expression *(works both in Ruby and Javascript)*:

```
^(?!^\d+$)[[:alnum:]]+$
```

This first ensures the string is not just digits by using a negative look ahead `(?!^[0-9]+$)`, then it matches one or more alphanumeric character, Unicode characters are supported which means this works with French letters too.

**EDIT:** If you only want English alphabet:

```
^(?!^\d+$)\w+$
```

[Rubular Demo](http://rubular.com/r/kD3aa3EaWk)

Comment: `\w` doesn't match accented letters. It's defined as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Comment: @theTinMan Doesn't `\w` support Unicode character as well as English ones. I am not sure, isn't there a single codepoint for those accented characters for languages like French. I look for a fix if my above thoughts are wrong.

Comment: @theTinMan I think I have found a better alternative. Thank you.

Comment: No, `\w` is *only* those characters: "[`/\w/ - A word character ([a-zA-Z0-9_])`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html)". And, no, Unicode doesn't have a "French" language set. French is incorporated into the Latin set, which also includes ["German, Italian, Vietnamese, Latin itself, and several other languages."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_%28Unicode%29).

Comment: Perl implements `\w` as a huge code base if the encoding is > 8-bit. What they are depends on locale, and is anybody's guess.

Comment: And this is Ruby, not Perl.

Comment: @TinMan - Not every flavor is ascii for \w. Most that support Unicode, have done \w conversion. And its mostly flaky.

Comment: Ruby only supports a small set for `\w` so what Perl or other languages do isn't germane to the question. If JavaScript implements full Perl compatibility or varies for `\w` to include alternate characters or codesets, then you might want to proceed along a JavaScript-specific line.

Comment: Does JS even support Unicode? By and large `\w` cast a very big Unicode code range and shouldn't be used in unicode mode. Perl has nothing to do with this, its the Unicode spec.

Comment: Thanks for the super-quick answer, I'm most likely to go with this one. I know I asked for support for french letters in my original question, but can you please provide me a version that is just confined to english alphanumeric only, excluding support for individual numbers? Basically just part 1) of my question. Thanks a ton for your help :)

Comment: @theTinMan Hot discussion here. I know from working with other languages that they have introduced Unicode support to `\w` making French or Chinese ... etc letters part of the match, if Ruby hasn't done so that is something else and surprising. Thank you for your explanations, problem solved.

Comment: @imaginonic You are welcome, I have edited my answer to cover your last request.

Comment: Thanks man, of all the answers, yours was the best and most concise :)

Answer (score 1):

For any Latin letters:

```
/(?=.*\p{Alpha})\p{Alnum}+/
```

Comment: Using the Unicode character-sets is probably the best path to go down until the OP defines which "French" characters are desired. Of course, the Latin set also works for Latin and Vietnamese and German, so it's possibly too wide of a net.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that you can't do what you want to do with one regex.  A single alpha character, anywhere in a group of numbers, will make it a valid match, and there is no way to represent that in regex, because what you are really saying is something along the lines of "a letter is required at the front of this word, but only if there isn't a letter in the middle or at the end", and regex won't do that.

Your best bet is to do two passes:

1. one that matches your alphanumeric, plus special "French" characters (pattern: TBD, based on what special characters you want to accept), and
2. one that matches numbers only (pattern: would include `[0-9]+` . . . need more information about the specific situation to give you a final, complete regex)

The values that you want in the end would need to pass the first regex and fail the second one.

Also . . .

To give you a better answer, we'll need to know a couple of things:

- Are you testing that an entire string matches the pattern?
- Are you trying to capture a single instance of the pattern in a bigger string?
- Are you trying to capture all of the instances of the pattern in a bigger string?

The answers to those questions have a big impact on the final regex pattern that you will need.

And, finally . . .

A note on the "French" characters . . . you need to be very specific about which special characters are acceptable and which aren't.  There are three main approaches to special character matching in regex: groups, additive, and subtractive

- groups - these are characters that represent a preset group of characters in the version of regex that you are using.  For example, `\s` matches all whitespaces
- additive - this is the process of listing out each acceptable character (or range of characters) in your regex.  This is better when you have a small group of acceptable characters
- subtractive - this is the process of listing out each UNacceptable character (or range of characters) in your regex.  This is better when you have a large group of acceptable characters

If you can clear up some of these questions, we should be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: Its probably better to do it in one pass. Since its so easy to do, why drag it out to something more complicated. The OP hilighted "English", yet he wants French characters. Its probable he just wants the extended ASCII accent characters as well as the normal ones.

Comment: @sln - Well, honestly, there is not enough information in the original question to tell if Sniffer's solution will work (which is why I was asking for more detail).  For example, if the input was a string of all of the sample data (i.e., `"4chan 9gag test91323432 asf5asdfaf35edfdfad afafaffe 92342424 343424 34432"`), and imaginonic is looking for all matches in the string, the pattern won't work, since it relies on a whole string match.  Then `\b(?!\b\d+\b)\w+\b` might work, but the `\b` matches different characters as "word characters" based on language, which could also throw the match off.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this  `^(?![0-9]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9\x80-\xa5]+$`

Edit - fixed cut&paste error and added Extended character range `\x80-\xa5`
which includes the accent chars (depending on locale set, the figures may be different)

Comment: Individually defining the accented characters desired by the OP is a losing game until the acceptable "French" letters are specified, as there are upper and lower-case variants for each that has to be added.

Comment: @TinMan - Well, I thought he just wanted those letters. For french, it might be the locale has to be set, then use \p{L} for them.

Comment: The OP needs to define the question a lot better. The base question is easy. Adding the accented question makes it wide-open and undefined, so it's too hard to answer correctly.

Comment: Sounds like he just wants ascii accent characters (they look French).

Comment: @theTinMan sorry for the confusing second part of my question, I have edited it out!

Comment: Be very careful with `\x80-\xa5`. It's assuming a lot about the encoding.